# Check for any running spark jobs on EMR using CLI or Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, boto3, amazon-emr

I am developing a module to delete the emr cluster but before deletion I need to check whether any spark jobs are running in the cluster. Is there a way we can check this using boto3 API call or through CLI command. Basically, I dont need any YARN applications in running state. In console we can find this in 'Application User Interfaces' tab, under High-level application history.

Comment: I am in a situation with the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?